# Macbook Air 2008 won't boot after error message asking to shut down due to low battery

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, battery

Yesterday my Macbook Air (original), model: a1237 flashed an error message
asking the user to shutdown due to low battery. Since it was not me, but my brother who was operating the macbook at that time, that I am not able to exactly put here what the error message was.

But, as I was told later, it prompted him to shutdown.

After that event, the Macbook when completely dead! It won't boot.

Here are the things that happen now, when I power it on:

- sleep light turns on
- keyboard lights are off
- the Apple logo on the lid doesn't turn on
- no chime, no sound, no display
- the fan works

It's like as if only the sleep led and the fan are the two working components in the macbook.

Things I tried:

- SMC reset
- Removing the battery and trying to switch it on AC (Is this a bad practice?)

None of these tricks worked!

I would be very grateful to you if you could help me on this one.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have a external USB with OS X to start from it? Did you try Safe mode or the Verbose mode ?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD 
No I don't have an external USB with OSX.

I tried to start in safe mode, it didn't work!

None of the components seems to be working, except the front sleep led and the fan of the logic board. No display, neither is its blacklight is on. Its completely black like it remains when the laptop is switched off.

The MagSafe idicator has been orange since the last 2-3 hours.

Could be a logic board or other critical hardware error?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't boot to a grey screen after resetting the SMC and then connecting a working charger for 15 minutes, you have a hardware issue.

The steps a hardware technician would perform are as follows:

- Disconnect everything you can from the Mac
- Try a power on when connected to power. (Observing whether the charge LED goes green or orange is an important clue to the health of the SMC/logic board and battery)
- Reset the NVRAM and try a boot with the option key held down listening for the blower to start up
- Charge for 10 minutes
- Reset the SMC again
- Now that things you can do externally are basically exhausted, now they would open the Mac case and proceed with observation/testing - perhaps with disconnect the battery and test charging and boot again

Comment: Thank you for the super quick reply :)
I will try the steps you mentioned but I have two doubts.

In the first point, you said disconnect everything you mean battery and power cable too or just connected peripherals?

As for the charger LED light is concerned, when the issue first occurred,
the light was a constant green (although the battery was completely drained). Now, after a day, it is a constant orange.

Recharged it for almost 2 hours, but it is still orange.

Comment: I would recommend not opening the Mac. When I say disconnect everything I mean all cables physically entering the Mac other than power. (USB, Firewire, thunderbolt, SD cards, etc...) The Air has few ports so that part might not apply. Either green light or orange light is good. That means you have enough power to properly reset the NVRAM and attempt a boot. The orange status for more than 8 hours means the charging hardware or battery has failed. You probably will need a battery since they last 1000 cycles and 5 years typically.

Comment: Just plugged in the power cable (without battery).
The MagSafe is showing a constant green.
I turned the power button on, the fan started rotating, sleep led got switched on and for the first time I noticed the logic board getting really hot in just 6-8 seconds of startup

Comment: Be careful - if the thermal sensors in the battery are needed to help govern cooling, you'll want to keep it connected / replace it.

Comment: could it be a logic board (or other critical hardware) issue?
I am from a remote city in India, repairing a Macbook means sending
it off more than 1200 miles away from home to a major city. Hence, I want to try out any trick under my capability before sending it off.